# Spring Webflux Reactor Netty: HTTP Request/Response Hex Dump?

Tags: spring-webflux, reactor-netty

What log level we have to set in application.properties in order to see the  full HTTP request and response with headers and body as a **hex dump** in the console from reactor-netty?

```
logging.level.reactor.netty=trace
```

Only shows response http headers.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 248
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1 ; mode=block
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Keep the logging level as DEBUG or TRACE and follow the instructions below:

1. If you want to see the `hex dump` for the server then you can customise it like this:

```java
@Component
public class MyNettyWebServerCustomizer
        implements WebServerFactoryCustomizer<NettyReactiveWebServerFactory> {
    @Override
    public void customize(NettyReactiveWebServerFactory factory) {
        factory.addServerCustomizers(httpServer -> httpServer.wiretap(true));
    }
}
```

2. If you want to see the `hex dump` for the client then you can customise it like this:

```java
WebClient.builder()
        .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(HttpClient.create().wiretap(true)))
        .build();
```

Comment: Works like a charm !

Comment: There is no out of the box spring boot application property settings for that?